# Ajax layout update

Tags: magento2, layout, layout-update

On product page I have popup opened on click on button. Its template is normally added to layout via **XML** and it's almost empty, but on click it content is replaced by ajax call.

So far controller instantiates another block, calls **toHtml()** and returns it as `text/html`. It works but, it is not elegant solution.

Is there any to better way to achieve it?